# For loop equivalent Swift 3

Tags: objective-c, swift, for-loop

I'm a bit confused. I have this code in Objective-C and I need to convert (get the same result) in swift. For example:

```
NSArray *cells = [self.someTableView visibleCells];

for (SomeTableViewCellClass *someCell in cells){
   // some coding
}
```

I have tried like this, but it throws an error that says the someCell was never used, consider to remove it:

```
for someCell in cells { // in this line
    let comeCell = SomeTableViewCellClass
    // some coding
}
```

But if I do it like this, it says that cannot convert values from one to another:

```
for someCell in cells as SomeTableViewCellClass { // in this line
        // some coding
}
```

I know that here are some posts about this question, but as much as I read them, they are a bit different and can be solved with my own code nr.2. I have a lot of loops like this in my Objective-C file, so I would appreciate if someone could help me and answer if there is any equivalent at all?!

Comment: the answer to this is literally all over the internet... heres a link to apples docs, so you dont have to google it yourself: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
for cell in cells {
    if let classCell = cell as? SomeTableViewCellClass {
        classCell.doSomething()
        // some coding
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for a quick answer. I believe that Eendje's answer will do the same, but your answer is more understandable for me. Works good, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

`visibleCells` returns an array of `UITableViewCell` elements.
In Objective-C you can write

```
for (SomeTableViewCellClass *someCell in cells) {
    // Do something with `someCell` ...

}
```

which tells the compiler: "I *know* that all array elements are
actually an instance of `SomeTableViewCellClass`. Just believe me."

That syntax does not exist in Swift, something similar would be a forced cast:

```
for someCell in someTableView.visibleCells as! [SomeTableViewCellClass] {
    // Do something with `someCell` ...

}
```

Both the Objective-C and the Swift code will crash if you are wrong,
i.e. if some cell is not an instance of `SomeTableViewCellClass`.

A safer solution is a for-loop with a case pattern:

```
for case let someCell as SomeTableViewCellClass in someTableView.visibleCells {
    // Do something with `someCell` ...

}
```

This enumerates all array elements which are an instance of the `SomeTableViewCellClass` subclass, and skips other elements.

Comment: This is nice feature. Do not know about it. Thanks.